# Mounting a USB storage device from memory

Tags: windows-10, usb, python, mount, emulator

As a pet project, I'm trying to develop some plausibly deniable encryption, the end goal being to mount a plaintext file system as a windows device **from memory** (there are multiple ways of doing this from a file, such as a .ISO or .IMG).

Unfortunately, it would simply be laughably insecure to write the plaintext filesystem to disk in order to mount it, as it would easily be recovered and would take time to erase. Surely there must be a program or python library to emulate a USB device with contents from memory, but from my research there seems to be none.

There are programs out there that do this as part of the whole encryption system, like Bitlocker, but these cannot be interfaced with.

I have researched multiple methods of doing this, such as PyFileSystem, IMDISK and OFSMount, but all of these either cannot mount a file system as a USB device, or must have an input from a file.

How can I emulate a storage device with contents, without saving it to disk?

Comment: I think you're looking for a "RAM Disk" application. [ERAM](https://github.com/Zero3K/ERAM) allows you to make a "storage device" up to 4GB in RAM, but this has nothing to do with emulating a USB device. Do you *really need* it to appear as a USB drive?

Comment: Hm? So what do you want, a RAM drive? There’s plenty available. Otherwise, just create your own FUSE file system.

Comment: I would like to be able to view it as a USB drive in windows explorer, rather than edit it through python

Comment: It looks like ERAM and WinFsp/FUSE could both be valid options

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I think I figured it out: Create a ramdisk through ERAM, write the files to it, then close it when done.